# Fast vectorized indexing in numpy

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization, python-2.x

Suppose we have an array of indices of another numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 3, 1])
b = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70])
```

We can use the array `a` as index directly:

```
b[a] # np.array([0, 30, 10])
```

But what if array a has more than one dimension? For example,

```
a = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]])
# I want to get b[a] = np.array([[0, 20], [10, 30], [20, 40]])
```

Numpy indexing doesn't work if the number of dimensions of a is greater than 1. We can achieve the desired result by using `map`

```
map(lambda x: b[x], a)
```

However, it is quite slow.  For 1-dimensional case, direct indexing is about 10-100 times faster than using `map`.

Is there a way to do it faster?

Comment: What happens with `b[a]`?

Comment: ``b[a]`` will work as desired even if ``a`` is 2D. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built-in [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) for exactly that same task -

```
np.take(b,a)
```

You can also flatten `a` with [`.ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html), index into `b` and reshape back to `a's` shape -

```
b[a.ravel()].reshape(a.shape)
```

These NumPy based approaches would be much better than `map(lambda x: b[x], a)` both in terms of both performance and memory as using `map` would give us list of arrays.

Sample run -

```
In [34]: a
Out[34]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 4]])

In [35]: b
Out[35]: array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70])

In [36]: np.take(b,a)
Out[36]: 
array([[ 0, 20],
       [10, 30],
       [20, 40]])

In [37]: b[a.ravel()].reshape(a.shape)
Out[37]: 
array([[ 0, 20],
       [10, 30],
       [20, 40]])
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [39]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(200,100))

In [40]: b = np.random.randint(0,100,(20000))

In [41]: %timeit map(lambda x: b[x], a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 643 µs per loop

In [42]: %timeit np.take(b,a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 105 µs per loop

In [43]: %timeit b[a.ravel()].reshape(a.shape)
1000 loops, best of 3: 231 µs per loop
```

Comment: In this case, `take` is doing the same as `b[a]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Yup! You are right, that works too! I guess for a case when `a` is a list, `.take()` could be used.

Comment: `np.take` was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem?  I can index `b` with a 2d array.  The output just matches `a1` in shape:

```
In [64]: b = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70])
In [65]: a1 = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]])
In [66]: b[a1]
Out[66]: 
array([[ 0, 20],
       [10, 30],
       [20, 40]])
```

`b[a1]` is not the same as `b[a1[:,0],a1[:,1]]`.  That is the 2 columns of `a1` do not provide two indices (which would require a 2d `b`).

Comment: Checked it again. You're right: it does work if a1 is numpy array. However, it doesn't if a1 is list (`[[0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]]`), which is why the question occured in the first place. I'll fix the question now.

Comment: You have your answer right there: `b[np.array(a)]`.  `b.take(a)` is a bit faster.